# Firebase ML kit give FirebaseMLException: Waiting for the text recognition model to be downloaded. Please wait

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I'm use firebase ml kit for text recognition but give this exception on emulator and real device.

```
W/System.err: com.google.firebase.ml.common.FirebaseMLException: Waiting for the text recognition model to be downloaded. Please wait.
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzjz.zzc(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzjz.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzic.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzhx.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zzhy.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_ml.zze.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Here my code

```
private fun MlProcessText(imageUri:Uri) {
    val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, imageUri)
    val textVision = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap)
    val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().onDeviceTextRecognizer

    detector.processImage(textVision).addOnSuccessListener { it ->
        val blocks = it.textBlocks
        if (blocks.size == 0 ){

            tvVision.text = "NO TEXT"
        }else{
            blocks.forEach {
                tvVision.append(" ${it.text}")
            }
        }

    }.addOnFailureListener {
        it.printStackTrace() // this is the exception log
        tvVision.text = it.message
    }
}
```

Also i tried :

**1-** *Settings->Apps->Google Play Services->Storage->Manage Space->Clear All Data*

**2-** Low storage check (At least 1Gig free)

And add meta-data

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.ml.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="ocr,text" />
```

But still the same error!

**UPDATE**

After getting stuck for several days i try to use **Google Mobile Vision**

So i add this to my dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'
```

And use [this article](https://medium.com/@prakash_pun/text-recognition-for-android-using-google-mobile-vision-a8ffabe3f5d6) for **OCR**  and in this code

```
    //Create the TextRecognizer
    final TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

    if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Detector dependencies not loaded yet");
    } else {

        //Initialize camerasource to use high resolution and set Autofocus on.
        mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecognizer)
                .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .setRequestedFps(2.0f)
                .build();
     }
```

`textRecognizer.isOperational()` return always `false`. that mean it does not work too . I think there is something common with this two problem.

So i am steel stuck on text recognizer for android !

Test on : Nox emulator , google Nexus 5X API 26 emulator and on Huawei p10  and Samsung Galaxy S7 real device.

is there any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

```
TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(this).build();

    if(!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
        // Note: The first time that an app using a Vision API is installed on a
        // device, GMS will download a native libraries to the device in order to do detection.
        // Usually this completes before the app is run for the first time.  But if that
        // download has not yet completed, then the above call will not detect any text,
        // barcodes, or faces.
        // isOperational() can be used to check if the required native libraries are currently
        // available.  The detectors will automatically become operational once the library
        // downloads complete on device.
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Detector dependencies are not yet available.");

        // Check for low storage.  If there is low storage, the native library will not be
        // downloaded, so detection will not become operational.
        IntentFilter lowstorageFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW);
        boolean hasLowStorage = registerReceiver(null, lowstorageFilter) != null;

        if (hasLowStorage) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Low Storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Low Storage");
        }
```

Comment: that's good point to check storage i do it and  hasLowStorage return false

Comment: Also try waiting sometime at (!textRecognizer.isOperational) as suggested in this link [link] (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/180)

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed that sometimes the problem is the **slow internet connection** and just need more time the model to be downloaded.
To minimize the bad user experience I've added this **warm up method** and call it as soon as the app starts, so when the actual recognition occurs the model to be already downloaded.

```java
/**
 * We call that on startup with hope the needed model will be downloaded as soon as possible;
 * It is used to prevent: "Waiting for the text recognition model to be downloaded. Please wait."
 * exception when recognizing.
 */
public static void warmUp() {
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    image.eraseColor(android.graphics.Color.GREEN);
    FirebaseVisionImage firebaseVisionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(image);
    FirebaseVision.getInstance().getOnDeviceTextRecognizer()
            .processImage(firebaseVisionImage)
            .addOnSuccessListener(null)
            .addOnFailureListener(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall updates from google play services.

Comment: Please go into more detail: Why, how, where.